# Is the particle reaction $π^- + p \to K^- + Σ^+$ possible?

Tags: particle-physics, textbook-erratum

I'm currently going over some undergraduate exams on particle physics and I'm having problems with a specific reaction, namely

$$
\pi^- + p \to K^- + \Sigma^+
$$

which, in my opinion, is not allowed due to strangeness violation ($0 \rightarrow -2$), so it could only be a weak interaction. Since it's purely hadronic, though, it should be a strong interaction. Can anyone explain to me where I'm wrong? Or is the professor's answer wrong? He marked the "not allowed" answer with "wrong" (no further explanation).

Comment: That's a good reason why it's not allowed. Of course, there could be multiple reasons, and it's not like nature checks them in a specific order.

Comment: wrong signs ? pi+p can go to K+ sigma+  :http://inspirehep.net/record/6000

Comment: if change in strangeness is greater than 1, then it is not allowed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This reaction is not possible, but for a nontrivial reason.

As you note, the non-conservation of strangeness forces this to be a weak interaction, but there is nothing stopping baryons from partaking in weak interactions (as in e.g. [this reaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#.CE.B2.E2.88.92_decay)). However, no charge is exchanged in the process, so it would be due to a weak neutral current, and [these do conserve strangeness](http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~muheim/teaching/np3/lect-ZandW.pdf).

The proton has an ($\mathrm{uud}$) configuration and the pion contains ($\mathrm{d \overline u}$); the Σ is ($\mathrm{uus}$) and the K is ($\mathrm{s \overline u}$). This means that you would need to turn two down quarks into strange quarks, i.e. something like this:

[image]

Such a [flavour-changing neutral current](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavor-changing_neutral_current) is as yet hypothetical, and has not been observed. (See for instance, the [Z boson Feynman rules](http://rjs.phys.uvic.ca/sites/rjs.phys.uvic.ca/files/lec16.pdf#page=8).)

Answer (score 5):

This reaction can proceed through multiple charged weak interactions (i.e. instances of a virtual $W$ boson being emitted or absorbed, the [flavor-changing weak processes of the standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabibbo%E2%80%93Kobayashi%E2%80%93Maskawa_matrix)); provided sufficient center-of-mass energy, of course. Schematically:

$$
\small{
\begin{array}{cc}
\pi^- \!\! \equiv \begin{Bmatrix} \overline u \cr d \end{Bmatrix} \cr
p ~ \equiv \begin{Bmatrix} u \cr u \cr d \end{Bmatrix}
\end{array}
\rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix} \overline u \cr \! u + W^- \!\! \cr u \cr u \cr d \end{bmatrix} \equiv
\begin{bmatrix} \overline u \cr u \cr \! W^- + u \cr u \cr d \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix} \overline u \cr u \cr s \cr u \cr d \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix} \overline u \cr u \cr s \cr u \cr u + W^- \!\! \end{bmatrix} \equiv
\begin{bmatrix} \overline u \cr u \cr s \cr \! W^- + u \! \cr u \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix} \overline u \cr u \cr s \cr s \cr u \end{bmatrix}
\equiv
\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{Bmatrix} \overline u \cr s \end{Bmatrix} \equiv K^- \cr
\begin{Bmatrix} u \cr u \cr s \end{Bmatrix} \equiv \Sigma^+
\end{array}
}
$$

But surely the cross section of this reaction, $\sigma[~\pi^- + p \rightarrow K^- + \Sigma^+~]$,
is expected to be quite small compared to $\sigma[~\pi^- + p \rightarrow K^0 + \Sigma^0~]$, for instance.